# Android Studio Can't Find Tesseract Headers in Native C++ Code

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, tesseract

I encountered an issue when trying to import "tess-two" module to my Android Studio Project. (I want to use tesseract in my Native C++ code.)

I imported tess-two as module, then copied jni folder under tess-two/src directory. (jni folder includes com_google_tesseract_android folder which has all tesseract header and .cpp files)

However, when i try to include those headers like:

```
#include  "com_googlecode_tesseract_android/tessbaseapi.cpp"
```

It autocompletes when i type #include "com_goog....", but gives the error:

```
fatal error: 'com_googlecode_tesseract_android/tessbaseapi.cpp' file not found
```

ps:

I added tess-two dependency to my app,
Same method when i try to include opencv works just fine,
I included leptonica too since tesseract is dependent on leptonica,
I'm using Ubuntu,
NDK Path is selected,
I dont use cmake, if there's no easy solution to this issue i will switch to using cmake

Thanks!

Comment: You have to include .hpp files, not .cpp

Comment: @JCWasmx86 thanks for your reply, unfortunately tesseract release doesn't have any files with .hpp extension. Same issue persists with .h files.

In my C++ code (Not Native, the template i wrote in C++) i included leptonica and tesseract as header files (#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>) and there was no problem there.